# Proof of convergence of $~\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2+7}{2n^4-n+3}~$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that the following infinite series converges.

$$\begin{align}
A:&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2+7}{2n^4-n+3}\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\underbrace{\left(\frac{1+\frac{7}{n^2}}{2-\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{3}{n^4}}\right)}_{=:f(n)}
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}f(n)\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}f(n)
\end{align}$$

$~f(n)~$approaches to $~\frac{1}{2}~$

$~\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}~$ approaches to $~\frac{\pi^2}{6}~$(for now I've only proven that this series converges at least though).

My right hand has stopped from the end of the 3rd line of equation.

How can I proceed from it?

I need your help.

Comment: $n^2+7\sim n^2$ and $2n^4-n+3\sim 2n^4$

Comment: Continuing your argument: $f(n)$ approaches $\frac{1}{2}$ as $n \to \infty$ and so $f(n) < 1$ for all large $n$ (actually, for all $n \ge 3$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. Then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n^2+7}{2n^4-n+3}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^4+7n^2}{2n^4-n+3}=1$$

This implies that both series converge.

Comment: Seems the rightmost value should be $~\frac{1}{2}~$

Answer (score 2):

Using the comparison test you have:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2+7}{2n^4-n+3}\sim \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2}{2n^4} =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} $$
and the last series converges.